# Putting \citep and \citep* together

Tags: citing, natbib

I'm using BibTeX and natbib and trying to make a single `\citep` block where two entries are expanded (i.e. I would cite them individually with `\citep*`) and one entry is not.  That is, the desired effect is

> (Marigo et al. 2001; Siess, Livio & Lattanzio 2002)

If I use `\citep{marigo+01,siess02}`, I'd get

> (Marigo et al. 2001; Siess et al. 2002)

and if I use `\citep*{marigo+01,siess02}`

> (Marigo, Girardi, Chiosi & Wood 2001; Siess, Livio & Lattanzio 2002).

If you're wondering why I don't just modify the bibliography style, it's because I'm following the MNRAS style which requires three-author papers are cited in full the first time and as et al. thereafter. For argument's sake, just imagine that the first paper is (Marigo, Girardi & Wood 2001) and I still want to mix the two modes.

I'm not sure if the search function (or Google) really picked up on my use of `\citep*` rather than `\citep` so I apologize if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reasonably straightforward (though kludgy!) solution I can see to the issue you describe is to use the composite instruction

```
\citetext{\citealp{marigo+01}; \citealp*{siess02}}
```

The `\citetext` instruction serves to surround its argument with parentheses. The `\citealp` and `\citealp*` instructions, respectively, behave like `\citep` and `\citep*` except that they do *not* surround the resulting text with parentheses.

Comment: I don't think it can be any less kludgy. Thanks!